# how get push keys in orderbykey formate on onvalue listener in firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I have key in this formate in my firebasedb I want to get those key in order by value formate in on valuelistner[image]

while I am trying that I am getting in different order

like this

```
  -KvhErzQOG2GE8XfzQhC 
  -KvhZRuIsl4ZbqNCrXt9
  -KvhZf3gwTsfOHsXP2M6
  -KvhLinnA_VC4KjFs_4Y: 
  -KvbPEAK39kHu98iW8Br: 
  -KvbPeRa4Bw8TEl8y5_J:
```

and my code look like this

```
 _messagesRef.child('xx').child('xxx').child('xxx').orderByKey().onValue.listen((Event event){
var response = event.snapshot.value;});
```

can any one help for this?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

I recommend listening to `onChildAdded`, which will fire in order and is what [the Flutter sample](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/example/lib/main.dart#L55-L58) does:

```
_messagesSubscription =
    _messagesRef.limitToLast(10).onChildAdded.listen((Event event) {
  print('Child added: ${event.snapshot.value}');
});
```

Alternatively you can listen to `onValue` and then loop over `event.snapshot.children`, but I don't have an example handy for that.

Comment: I want for onvalue  listner not child added and  and in onvalue listner orderbykey().limittolast(x) i dont that x and i dont want to hit data base multiple times

Comment: Thank u for giving response and i am getting properly for child added but i want in onvalue